# how can I load invalid certification web page using JavaFX.

Tags: javafx-webengine

Hi  I am trying to load web page in webView pannel in JAVAFX. 
I am able to load the web page whose certification is valid like google,yahoo. But unable to load invalid certification Sites.

Please suggest how can I add certification to my Web Site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the certificate cannot be found in default java certificates store.

Try to create java truststore with the root certificate from the "invalid certification sites". Command similar to this:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias somealias -file certificate.crt -deststorepass somePassword -destkeystore truststore.jks
```

Then start your java program with VM options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="pathto\truststore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="somePassword" -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Additional option -Djavax.net.debug=all allows you to debug the ssl handshake and see potential errors with certificates.